# calculate date difference in hours using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

**Scenario**

I have an array of objects with multiple users with their attendances(in time, out time). I'm trying to use Array​.prototype​.reduce() to minimize the code.

Following is the sample object/array, the in and out can be more depending on the user.

```
"temp": [
        {
            "name": "Test User",
            "id": 35,
            "Attendance": [
                {
                    "id": 34890,
                    "employee_code": "AL028",
                    "date": "2018-11-20",
                    "time": "2018-11-20T10:11:06.000Z",
                    "flag": "0\t1\t0\t0\t0",
                    "type": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "id": 34904,
                    "employee_code": "AL028",
                    "date": "2018-11-20",
                    "time": "2018-11-20T13:12:23.000Z",
                    "flag": "1\t1\t0\t0\t0",
                    "type": "OUT"
                },
                {
                    "id": 34914,
                    "employee_code": "AL028",
                    "date": "2018-11-20",
                    "time": "2018-11-20T13:46:18.000Z",
                    "flag": "0\t1\t0\t0\t0",
                    "type": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "id": 34943,
                    "employee_code": "AL028",
                    "date": "2018-11-20",
                    "time": "2018-11-20T16:00:02.000Z",
                    "flag": "1\t1\t0\t0\t0",
                    "type": "OUT"
                },
            ]
        }
  ]
```

**Code**

> Please Ignore few variables which I've kept for logging purpose

```
let temp = attendances;
        let mappedAttendance = temp.map(emp => {
          let hours = 0,i=0;
          const empHours = emp.Attendance.reduce((firstEle, secondEle) => {
            if (
              firstEle.type === "IN" &&
              secondEle.type === "OUT" &&
              (firstEle !== undefined && secondEle !== undefined)
            ) {              
              hours +=
                Math.abs(
                  new Date(firstEle.time).getTime() -
                    new Date(secondEle.time).getTime()
                ) / 36e5;
            }            
            i++;
            return hours;            
          });          

          return {
            name: emp.name,
            id: emp.id,
            hours: empHours
          };
        });
```

**Goal**

Also I want the output to be like follow

```
       {
            "name": "Test User",
            "id": 35,
            "hours": 3.0213888888888887
        },
```

**Problem**

It seems it's not calculating well as after first iteration the returning value will be firstEle and it's hours which is calculated in the first iteration and it's causing the problem for calculating, I've tried multiple ways but I'm not coming up with the solution on how to make this reduce work.

**UPDATE**

Karamell's answer was perfect but I'm still having a difficult time achieving the following condition in reduce
Also, I managed to get exactly what I wanted with the following,
As if there is IN,OUT,OUT it won't calculate last OUT which is what I wanted

```
          let hours = 0;          
          emp.Attendance.reduce((firstEle, secondEle) => {
            if (
              firstEle.type === "IN" &&
              secondEle.type === "OUT" &&
              (firstEle !== undefined && secondEle !== undefined)
            ) {
              hours +=
                Math.abs(
                  new Date(firstEle.time).getTime() -
                    new Date(secondEle.time).getTime()
                ) / 36e5;
            }
            return secondEle;
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want very concise code

```
emp.Attendance.reduce(
  ([result, lastIn], { time, type }) =>
    type === 'OUT' ? [result + (new Date(time) - lastIn)] : [result, new Date(time)],
  [0],
) /
  (1000 * 60 * 60);
```

It returns 5.2502... for your data which is probably correct.

You haven't specified what should happen if the data doesn't match up, in terms of in/out pairs, but this should work for correct data.

Comment: This work's perfect, but I'm having hard time grasping what you did at some points specially with []. 
Also yes I haven't specified what should happen but I was more thinking like it should only calculate if first element is IN and second is OUT otherwise ignore the element, as there can be countless scenarios for inconsistent IN and OUT which can't be handled at some level. I hope you understand what I want .

Comment: For example IN,OUT,OUT it should only calculate the difference between first IN,OUT and it should exclude last OUT as there is no IN.

Comment: Indeed, if you're aiming for compact, reduce oriented code if will often be harder to read (but easier to write if you've done it a lot).  Because there are two things to keep track of here, the accumulated time and the last IN time, it will use a double accumulator destructured array. Now that you hopefully understand the workings of this code, you can adjust it to your needs. Or perhaps better yet choose another approach altogether that is less compact and more explicit.

Comment: I'm still having difficulties understanding the [result, lastIn], I understood that the {time, type} are values of current element. I'm trying to log few things but it's giving me error. Can you please explain little regarding what you passed as accumulator?

Comment: I tried     emp.Attendance.reduce(([result, lastIn], { time, type }) => {
              console.log(result, lastIn);
              return (
                type === "OUT"
                  ? [result + (new Date(time) - lastIn)]
                  : [result, new Date(time)],
                [0]
              );
            }) /
            (1000 * 60 * 60);

Comment: You accidentally put the `[0]` argument on the wrong place. This is the initial argument for your accumulator. Here is the corrected version of your code: .reduce(([result, lastIn], { time, type }) => { console.log(result, lastIn); return ( type === "OUT" ? [result + (new Date(time) - lastIn)] : [result, new Date(time)]); }, [0]) / (1000 * 60 * 60); Read up on: The reduce function signature, array destructuring, tenary operator, type coercion is Javascript (in particular, here the Date.prototype.valueOf is being used)